# cakePHP non ORM query results, how can it be done?

Tags: arrays, cakephp, orm

How can i get the data from a query as a flat, non-indexed array?
I can't use the 'list' option since i need it to be done with a `query()` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Cake always returns results as an array with named keys you're bound to apply some post processing.

You can achieve the desired result, either by using a plain `foreach` loop to manipulate the array to your liking, or by using one of the methods from the Core Utility Library included in Cake. [`Set::combine`](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1492/combine) might be what you're looking for.